# How to shuffle data without ml framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was trying to use `numpy.random_shuffle`, but didn't work well

```
import numpy as np

data=loaddat('mydatapath')
np.random_shuffle(data)
```

it didn't work. Then I have tried:

```
np.random.shuffle(data)
```

but it didn't work too

What function I have to use to shuffle my loaded data?

Comment: `a = [1,2,3,4,5]; numpy.random.shuffle(a); print(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [numpy.random.permutation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```py
import numpy as np

SPLIT = 20 # leave [:20], 

data = loaddat('mydatapath')

order = np.random.permutation(len(data))

train = data[order[SPLIT:]]
test = data[order[:SPLIT]]
```